# To obtain records from a table in excel by entering a unique data

Tags: excel

I have series of contact records in an excel file. I don't want to be re-entering the record every month. i want to obtain a record from the contact table by entering just the phone number. Please help!

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide sample code of what you have already done. Users here can be very helpful with specific questions, but not doing your homework.

Answer (score 0):

Without having a specific example I know I've used Vlookup in the past for what it sounds as if you are describing. @pnuts suggestion was also a good one with the INDEX MATCH suggestion.

Here is a description and example of both online. If you can share yours we might be able to help more

http://www.randomwok.com/excel/how-to-use-index-match/

-Cheers